# Conversion of 24 hours date/time to 12 hours format and vice-versa

Tags: python, datetime

`date` is in this format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`[this is 24 hours].I want to convert this date in 12 hours something like this -> `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p`
and `vice-versa`.
How can i achieve this?? Thanx!

Comment: Presumably you have string input and want string output? Have you tried anything yourself yet, you *already* have string formats there.

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the string into a datetime object via [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), then dump via [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) in the desired format:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> d  # d is a string
'2016-04-28 07:46:32'
>>> datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")
'2016-04-28 07:46:32 AM'
```

Note that the `%I` here is a [12-hour clock](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Thank you ! @alecxe..and vice-versa..I mean again wanted to 24 of 12 hours then???

Comment: @Pranay make the same procedure, but now `strptime` using `%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p` and `strftime` using `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.

Answer (score 2):

24 hour to 12-hour

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2016-05-25 13:45:56', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 25, 13, 45, 56)
>>> dt=datetime.strptime('2016-05-25 13:45:56', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')
'2016-05-25 01:45:56 PM'
>>>
```

12-hour to 24-hour

```
>>> dt=datetime.strptime('2016-05-25 01:45:56 PM', '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 25, 13, 45, 56)
>>> dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2016-05-25 13:45:56'
>>>
```

Comment: How do I convert something like 12:00 AM into 00:00:00 ?

Comment: @chanchalpardeshi you could use something like this `dt=datetime.strptime('12:00 AM', '%I:%M %p')` and then `dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')` which will print `'00:00:00'`

Comment: This saved my ass