# converting string to int using map dosen't include zero

Tags: python, python-3.x

My input to this is in the format 07:05:09PM
expected output:

```
19:05:09
```

output got:

```
19:5:9
```

---

```
def timeConversion(s):

    if "AM" in s:
        print(s[1:8])
    else:
        string=s.split(':')
        print(string)
        string.append(string[2][0:2])
        string.remove(string[2])
        print(string)
        date=list(map(int, string))
        print(date)
        a=date[0]+12
        b='%s:%s:%s' % (a, date[1], date[2])
        return b
```

My question is when I convert the date from string to int using map the zero is not picked up, is there any way to get the integer as such???

Comment: If you care about leading zeros, you're not treating your data as integers. You're treating it as sequences of characters, and you shouldn't be calling `int` at all.

Comment: Your problem isn't with `map`, it's with how you're formatting your string. I'd start there :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a custom function for formatting datetimes, you can get the intended output by formatting your string when you print it. Replace this line

```
b='%s:%s:%s' % (a, date[1], date[2])
```

with this:

```
b='%02d:%02d:%02d' % (a, date[1], date[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

there are functions for converting 24h to 12h time :

> Load the string into a datetime object via `strptime()`, then dump via `strftime()` in the desired format:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
d  # d is a string '2016-04-28 07:46:32'
datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")
'2016-04-28 07:46:32 AM'
```

> Note that the `%I` here is a 12-hour clock

[Conversion of 24 hours date/time to 12 hours format and vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913684/conversion-of-24-hours-date-time-to-12-hours-format-and-vice-versa)

if you want to use your solution you can add *leading zeros* to integrs like in [How to add Trailing zeroes to an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688196/how-to-add-trailing-zeroes-to-an-integer) :

```
numbers = [1, 19, 255]
numbers = [int('{:<03}'.format(number)) for number in numbers]
```

you can print leading zeros like in [Display number with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)